# How to handle click event to change value in array to true

Tags: reactjs

I want to make a handleItemClick event to toggle the value in done to true, how can I do it? I am struggling to understand how to change it. Thanks a lot for your help I realll appreciate it

```
const TodoItem = (props) => <li onClick={props.onClick}>{props.item.text}</li>

class TodoList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { items, onClick } = this.props;
    return (<ul onClick={onClick}>
      {items.map((item, index) => 
                 <TodoItem item={item} key={index} onClick={this.handleItemClick.bind(this, item)}/>)}
    </ul>);
  }

  handleItemClick(item, event) {
    // Write your code here
  }
}


const items = [ { text: 'Buy grocery', done: true },
  { text: 'Play guitar', done: false },
  { text: 'Romantic dinner', done: false }
];

const App = (props) => <TodoList
  items={props.items}
  onItemClick={(item, event) => { console.log(item, event) }}
/>;

document.body.innerHTML = "<div id='root'></div>";
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App items={items}/>, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current setup, the `items` are passed in as props. At some point, these items need to become component state so that they can be updated.

One option is to accept the items as props and use them as the initial state in the `TodoList`. However, what you like want is for the `App` component to have these set as the initial state in the `useState` hook.

Then pass the `onItemClick` prop so that a click on the `TodoItem` component can call this method and update the proper item.

```js
const TodoItem = props => (
  <li onClick={props.onClick}>
    {props.item.text} - {props.item.done.toString()}
  </li>
);

class TodoList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { items, onItemClick } = this.props;

    return (
      <ul>
        {items.map((item, index) => (
          <TodoItem item={item} key={index} onClick={() => onItemClick(item)} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

const App = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([
    { text: "Buy grocery", done: true },
    { text: "Play guitar", done: false },
    { text: "Romantic dinner", done: false }
  ]);

  return (
    <TodoList
      items={items}
      onItemClick={itemToUpdate => {
        const updatedItems = items.map(item => {
          if (item === itemToUpdate) {
            return { ...item, done: !item.done };
          } else {
            return item;
          }
        });
        setItems(updatedItems);
      }}
    />
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have App own the list of todo items and pass the items and setItems function you got from setState.

Using setState and passing it has a disadvantage because you can't easily use useCallback to optimize the handlers but the following will work:

```
const TodoItem = props => (
  <li onClick={props.onClick}>
    {props.item.text} {String(props.item.done)}
  </li>
);

const TodoList = ({ items, setItems }) => {
  const onClick = id => () =>
    setItems(
      items.map(item =>
        item.id === id
          ? { ...item, done: !item.done }
          : item
      )
    );
  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map(item => (
        <TodoItem
          item={item}
          //never use index for list especially if you remove
          // or re arrange them
          key={item.id}
          onClick={onClick(item.id)}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

const App = props => {
  //someone needs to own items so when you change it
  // it will cause a re render
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    { id: 1, text: 'Buy grocery', done: true },
    { id: 2, text: 'Play guitar', done: false },
    { id: 3, text: 'Romantic dinner', done: false },
  ]);
  return <TodoList items={items} setItems={setItems} />;
};
```